# draw simple touches GestureOverlawView Android

Tags: android, gestureoverlayview

Is there a way to enhance a `GestureOverlayView` in order to let it draw points when user just touches the screen?

I tried to get its Canvas and draw on it, but it seems that it doesn't use one, or it's private.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `gestureStrokeLengthThreshold` lower? Looks like the default is 50.

Comment: Yes, tried it but it doesn't work :/ Seems that `GestureOverlayView` just catches `MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL`

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing that, but `GestureOverlayView` handles all the regular touch events - like `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, etc. - but not `ACTION_SCROLL`. Anyhoo, there's a coupla reasons it won't draw a point by default, one being the `Path` it draws just does a `moveTo()` on `ACTION_DOWN`, and there's a minimum tolerance of 3 in either axis hardcoded in `ACTION_MOVE`. If you want, it's a pretty simple `View` class. You could just copy the source and modify it to do a move event on the down, and adjust the tolerance a bit. I just did it relatively quickly, for to test.